# PHP PDO: Could not find driver

Tags: php_pdo, php, postgresql, mysql

В общем такая проблемка, решил тут переписать скрипты на PDO, чтобы стать БДнезависимым, но возникли проблемы. Система стоит Debian Squeeze, установлен apache2, php, php-mysql, php-pgsql. Все библиотеки подключены, такие как pdo.so, pdo_mysql.so, pdo_pgsql.so и phpinfo() говорит, что все нормально, но при попытке подключения:

```
<?php
define (DB_DRIVER,  "mysql");
define (DB_CHARSET, "UTF8");
define (DB_HOST,    "localhost");
define (DB_USER,    "developer");
define (DB_PASS,    "developer");
define (DB_NAME,    "DEVELOPER");

try {
    $db = new PDO($DB_DRIVER . ":host=" . $DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

DB_DRIVER пытался присваивать и "pdo_mysql" и "pgsql" и "pdo_pgsql" результат всегда один и тот же - "Error: could not find driver". Естественно если не использовать PDO соединения с базами проходят нормально. Да, кстати, даже включал логирование MySQL, чтобы проверить наверняка... В логах пусто. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как говорят, наши англоязычные друзья на stackoverflow

> `You need to have a module called pdo_mysql. Looking for following in phpinfo(),
>   pdo_mysql
>   PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version => 5.1.44`

**//UPD**

При всем уважении, прочитайте, как работать с ***DEFINE()***. Сразу не посмотрел.

```
<?php
define (DB_DRIVER,  "mysql");
define (DB_CHARSET, "UTF8");
define (DB_HOST,    "localhost");
define (DB_USER,    "developer");
define (DB_PASS,    "developer");
define (DB_NAME,    "DEVELOPER");

try {
    $db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER.":host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER, DB_PASS);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: у меня pdo_mysql установлен и подключен и pdo_pgsql тоже и в phpinfo() все это написано и версия первого 5.1.49, а второго 8.4.10. И этот пост на стэке я читал, только вот свет на ошибку это не пролило. Вот вам даже пруфпик http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37021966/pdo.png

Comment: обновил ответ. принимай.

Comment: Мда. Бывает)))) Принимаю. Спасибо.

Comment: внимательнее нужно быть иногда. ;)

Comment: @Shrek, про работу с константами вам тоже не помешает освежить память :) Правильно так:

    define('DB_DRIVER',  "mysql");
    define('DB_CHARSET', "UTF8");
    define('DB_HOST',    "localhost");
    define('DB_USER',    "developer");
    define('DB_PASS',    "developer");
    define('DB_NAME',    "DEVELOPER");

Либо так:

    const DB_DRIVER = "mysql";
    const DB_CHARSET = "UTF8";
    const DB_HOST = "localhost";
    const DB_USER = "developer";
    const DB_PASS = "developer";
    const DB_NAME = "DEVELOPER";

Comment: Ну да строковые данные должны быть, я не про это @Ilya Pirogov 

еще по разному использовать их можно 

>class constanta
>{
>const  VALUE= 132456;
>}
>define('VALUE', 654321);
>
>
>echo constanta::VALUE. "\n" . VALUE;

выведет знаешь что?

> 123456 654321

[ссыль][1] тут тоже обсуждалось по поводу того как лучше делать константы, кому что удобнее, все равно :)


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/35155/